# jquery ui autocomplete with json response

Tags: json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've tried [Simon Whatley's plugin](http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/using-jquery-auto-complete-with-coldfusion) for jQuery autocomplete but I've found out that the plugin expects the autocomplete results to be on individual lines, and there's no need for json.

So, I searched for other plugins that will accept json and I found [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp). In the documentation, there's not much example in using json data. I can't make this work with my code. I also looked into other sites for help but to no avail.

Here is the code for my query:

```
<cfif url.q neq ''>
    <cfset theQ = lcase(q)>

    <cfquery datasource="names" name="qry" maxrows="20">
        select top 10 id, name
        from sample
        where
        lower(name) like '#theQ#%'
        order by name
    </cfquery>

    <!---
    Before we can serialize the query, we need to convert
    it to an array of structs.
    --->
    <cfset rows = [] />

    <!--- Loop over the query to convert it. --->
    <cfloop query="qry">

    <!--- Create a row struct. --->
        <cfset row = {} />

        <!--- Add each column to our struct. --->
        <cfloop
        index="column"
        list="#qry.columnList#"
        delimiters=",">

            <cfset row[ column ] = qry[ column ][ qry.currentRow ] />

        </cfloop>

    <!--- Append the row struct to the row array. --->
        <cfset arrayAppend( rows, row ) />

    </cfloop>

    <!---
    Now that we have converted our query to an
    array of structs, we can serialize it using the
    serializeJSON() method.
    --->
    <cfset serialized=#serializeJSON(rows)#>
    <cfoutput>#serialized#</cfoutput>

</cfif>
```

The json data I get looks like this:

```
[{"NAME":"levi","ID":7},{"NAME":"leviticus","ID":3}]
```

Now, here is for the autocomplete:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#q").autocomplete({
          source: function(request, response){
            $.post("data/country.cfm", {data:request.term}, function(data){     
              response($.map(data, function(item) {
              return {
                label: item.id,
                value: item.name
              }
              }))
            }, "json");
          },
          minLength: 2,
          dataType: "json",
          cache: false,
          focus: function(event, ui) {
            return false;
          },
          select: function(event, ui) {
             this.value = ui.item.label;
             return false;
          }
         });
       });
    </script>
```

What can the problem be? Any help please? Thank you.

Comment: try to do it like this , label: item.ID, : item.Name , hope it shall work.

Comment: @Furqan, thanks but still doesn't work. There's no search results that appear. I'm wondering if it really enters the autocomplete function. How will I know?

Comment: put "debugger;" on the first line of the response function and enable script debugging in IE, then you can debug it through JS debugger.

Comment: Hi! I have solved this problem by trying out this site: http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/18/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-coldfusion/ It worked perfectly! Thanks!